# .Net Core Library in .Net Standard: Core Long Path Handling

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

How would one use a .Net Core library in a regular .Net application? I came across [this](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToReferenceANETCoreLibraryInWinFormsOrNETStandardExplained.aspx) Hanselman article that explains I should be using a .Net Standard library. Problem is, my code only works in a Core Library (afaik).

The below method works in Core but not in a Standard library. It appears that Core handles long paths (over the 250 char limit) better than regular .Net solutions ([Background](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jeremykuhne/2016/06/21/more-on-new-net-path-handling/)).

Is there a way to use a Core library in a regular .Net library?

```
private static List<FileInfo> FastGetFileList(string myBaseDirectory, string searchString = "*.*")
{
    var dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(myBaseDirectory);

    return dirInfo.EnumerateDirectories()
        .AsParallel()
        .SelectMany(di => di.EnumerateFiles(searchString, SearchOption.AllDirectories)).ToList()
        .Union(dirInfo.EnumerateFiles(searchString)).ToList();
}
```

**Full Solution for Testing**

This will fail in a regular console app and also doesn't work when called from a .Net Standard 2.0 library. In a Core console app, it will work.

```
private string path =
            @"\\GREATER THAN 250 CHARACTERS NETWORK FOLDER LOCATION"
        ;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var temp = FastGetFileList(path);

        Console.WriteLine("Success");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static List<FileInfo> FastGetFileList(string myBaseDirectory, string searchString = "*.*")
    {
        var dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(myBaseDirectory);

        return dirInfo.EnumerateDirectories()
            .AsParallel()
            .SelectMany(di => di.EnumerateFiles(searchString, SearchOption.AllDirectories)).ToList()
            .Union(dirInfo.EnumerateFiles(searchString)).ToList();
    }
```

Comment: What version of .Net Framework is your app targetting?

Comment: @DavidG It's flexible, but ideally 4.5. But it could go up in order to get this to work.

Comment: If you're not targetting 4.6.2 or above, have you added in the `AppContextSwitchOverrides` element to your app.config?

Comment: When Microsoft were talking about .NET Core 2.0 prior to the release, they said that .NET Core would be able to consume .NET Framework assemblies. I've done this successfully, but not the other way around. Which version of .NET Core / .NET Standard are you targetting?

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2017/08/14/announcing-net-core-2-0/

Comment: @DavidG If I set it to lower than 4.6.2 and add in the AppContext switch I get a 'Could not find a part of the path' error. Same if I go above 4.6.2. If I go lower without the AppContext switch it becomes an Path Too Long exception.

Comment: @series0ne I'm flexible on that too, can use 1.0 <-> 2.0. Whatever to get it to work.

Comment: @windowskm I'd be inclined to try your code (above) in a .NET Standard 2.0 class library (as opposed to .NET Core) as they can be referenced easily by .NET Framework. (I know you said it doesn't work in .NET Standard, but there were something like 32,000+ new APIs added to 2.0, so I'm just wondering if that will help matters)

Comment: @series0ne Nope, tried a .Net Standard library 2.0 and get the same 'Could not find a part of the path' error. Seems only in a Core Library do I not receive the error.